# Search next (bigger) key with SQL efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with  tuples where timestamps (time) are not consecutive but (we can assume for simplicity) unique.

```
time | value
------------
0    |4
3    |2
5    |6
8    |10
9    |5
13   |-1
15   |-3
...  |...
```

I am faced with the problem of finding the "next tuple given some time T" ( <- next(T);), e.g. next(4) -> <5,6>, or next(5) -> <8,10>. Further, since this data is hold in a MySQL database I would prefer to realize this with SQL. However, time constraints require to find the respective tuple in O (log n).

At first glance, I tried the following SQL statement (I hope my Pseudo-code is understandable):

```
<time, value> = next(T) {

    return (select * from table
        where time = (select min(time) from table
            where time > T))
}
```

However, this does not give the result in reasonable time. I guess that "select min(time) from table where time > find" takes O(n) time. Of course, I know performing a search in an ordered list takes only O(log n) time but I have no clue how to do that in SQL. Is this even possible? If so, how does it work?

Thanks!

---

For your information:

(1) At the moment my solution caches the respective data in memory and orders it initially. This way I can then find the next tuple in O(log n) time. However, this consumes lots of memory and I would prefer to do it kind of "in-line" in the DBMS which is surely highly optimized regarding caching etc.

(2) I could imagine a solution where data is hold ordered by time in the database, but I don't know how to ensure ordering or to implement a respective search algorithm in SQL. :-/

(3) I am aware of indexing etc. and that it improves performance if I declare time as primary key but I don't know how it could help to find next in O(log n).

Comment: Yes, I do. I guess this way "select * from table where time = min" takes only O(log n), but still finding the min takes O(n), right?

Comment: No, if the index is utilized correctly, you are already at O(log n) performance. Query optimization can be tricky. Sometimes MySQL's internal query optimizer produces unexpected results. Therefor, if you have problems with the performance of a query, you should first have a look at the execution plan. You can do this by using "explain <statement>". You will need a bit to figure out the meaning of the output, but it's worth the time if you have do this more regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to make sure that an index exists for the time column. You can check if an index exists by examining the results of this command:

   `show index from table;`

   If the time column is the primary key of the table, then the index almost certainly exists. The index is necessary for an efficient search in the time column. You will get O(log n) performance <del>with the right index, if not constant time lookups</del> (just read more about btrees).

   MySQL uses B-tree indexes, which allow lookup and sequential traversing, both in logarithmic time. That means that finding the next higher time for a given time is done in logarithmic time, provided that MySQL utilizes the index correctly. This is not always the case and you have to try this. If it does not work, you have to give MySQL execution hints to make it utilizing the index correctly.
2. Order the results by time and then use the `limit` keyword for taking only the first result from the result set:

   ```
   select * from table
       where time > T
       order by time
       limit 1
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the "limit" command. I can imagine that "order by time limit 1" takes only O (log n), but are you sure that with "where time > T" it does not take O(n)?

Comment: Well, try it ;) examine the execution plan and/or do performance tests. This is the only way to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, in Microsoft SQL Server "select top 1 * from table where time > T order by time desc" does it in O(log n). Thanks a lot!